ERROR: materialized views may not be defined using bound parameters. How can I create materialized view via JPA?
My goal is to create different materialized views in PostreSQL database in runtime and I want to use for it Spring JPA EntityManager and Hibernate. I have reserched similar questions on the stackoverflow but none of them solving my problem and I really hope for advice here. I use Spring Boot 3.3.3, Hibernate 6 and PostrgreSQL.
My problem is: how can I configure native sql query with different types parameters (name of view, conditions) to successfully create a new materialized view in the postgres database?
I hava a table Question like this:
create table if not exists question(
        id uuid primary key not null,
        type uuid not null, -- maps to Type table
        content text unique not null,
        grade int not null,
        created_at timestamp with time zone
);

I tried to use some kind like the example below
Query query = entityManager.createNativeQuery(
        "create materialized view if not exists :name as" +
                " select * from question q" +
                " where" +
                " q.type in (:typesList)" +
                " and" +
                " q.grade <= :maxGrade" +
                " and" +
                " q.grade >= :minGrade"
)
.setParameter("name", name) // String name
.setParameter("typesList", list) // List<UUID> list
.setParameter("maxGrade", maxGrade) // Integer maxGrade
.setParameter("minGrade", minGrade); // Integer minGrade

query.executeUpdate();

But it executes with exception (this exceptions tells me about position of first parameter (:name) in the query):
JDBC exception executing SQL [create materialized view if not exists ? as select * from question q where q.type in (?,?) and q.grade <= ? and q.grade >= ?] [ERROR: syntax error at or near "$1"
On the next step I stopped using parameter for name of view and my query looked like this:
Query query = entityManager.createNativeQuery(
        "create materialized view if not exists " + name + " as" +
                " select * from question q" +
                " where" +
                " q.type in (:typesList)" +
                " and" +
                " q.grade <= :maxGrade" +
                " and" +
                " q.grade >= :minGrade"
)
.setParameter("typesList", list) // List<UUID> list
.setParameter("maxGrade", maxGrade) // Integer maxGrade
.setParameter("minGrade", minGrade); // Integer minGrade

query.executeUpdate();

This also fails with exception:
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: materialized views may not be defined using bound parameters
Finnally only case that works correctly is:
Query query = entityManager.createNativeQuery(
        "create materialized view if not exists " + name +" as" +
            " select * from question" +
            " where" +
            " type in (" + buildTypeCondition(list) + ")" +
            " and" +
            " grade <= " + (maxGrade) +
            " and" +
            " grade >= " + (minGrade)
);

//buildTypeCondition here creates a string like "'<uuid1>', '<uuid2>', ..."

But its really bad code and to avoid SQL-injections I need to get rid of injections of string parameters directly into sql query.
Can you please help me, how should I use parameters correctly in this case? How should I create a valid IN (uuid, uuid, ...) SQL condition from List<UUID> parameter?

I don't think you can. This is not a Hibernate problem, it is how PostgreSQL works. Furthermore, I don't think you should. You can probably get what you want with a small number of materialized views that you can create with hard-coded values rather than with all filters. Then, when you select you need to add the filters in the query instead. Having a large number of very specific materialized views is going to be expensive.

@ewramner there should not be a lot o views, but all of them provides access to most usually readed data so it will be very useful and available to use views instead of select with conditions

If there are not a lot of views you should be able to generate them ahead of time rather than on demand and in that case you don't need bind variables as the parameters are known.

You keep asking questions about materialized views so I have a feeling that you try to use wrong tool to solve your problem. It may help if you ask a question about your actual goal.

DDL statements do not support parameters. You have to generate SQL and sanitize parameters manually.
You don't need EntityManager, there is no entity to manage. Use DataSource.
Generating materialized views at runtime sounds sketchy. And won't work easily with Hibernate. Think about different solution.
Here is buildTypeCondition implementation:
private static String buildTypeCondition(List<UUID> uuids) {
    return uuids.stream()
            .map(uuid -> "'%s'".formatted(uuid))
            .collect(Collectors.joining(", "));
}

